# One thing from Brian Beckman's Tyre Phisics is missing - any idea of this...?

Tags: game-physics

reading the Brian Beckman's paper on combining tire forces i found that, one of the things requires a bit more in terms of physics knowledge.

Brian does not mention a method of finding the maximum positive grip for the current tire load - "**The maximum positive grip occurs, just by eyeball, around  = 0.08.** " - this is a quote of this part where he explains a method of combining the forces: http://phors.locost7.info/phors25.htm

This is for finding the combined slip !

**"Using secret physicist methods, I've found that this curve crosses the horizontal axis - that is, goes to zero - at precisely  = 0.0796....."**

Is there someone who has implemented Brian Beckman's method or is into these things in general and if so i wonder, does actually finding the maximum grip of a tire based on the current load of the tire requires using of some specialized functions or i am probably missing something because it seams this is important for calculating final force !

Thank You !

Comment: The question tuns out to be actually - " how to find the optimal slip value for a given curve" !?

Comment: Isn't that just the zero of the derivative?

Comment: Not sure, my math skills are not good enough to understand this !